# Changing Language Settings for Zimbabwe

Tags: language-support

Zimbabwe has now moved to a multi-currency system, and the Zimbabwe Dollar is no more. Generally, prices throughout the country are now quoted in USD, so could you point me to the right people to remove the "Z" from in front of the dollar sign for English/Zimbabwe regional settings?

I do realize that this is not specifically an Ubuntu issue, but I don't know who to contact to inform them that the regional settings for Zimbabwe are outdated.

Could someone please point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: See below for an actual answer to your question. If you just want to change it locally, edit /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_ZW and remove <U005A> from int_curr_symbol and currency_symbol

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to file a bug against the langpack-locales package: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/langpack-locales/+filebug